# SqlDelight/SQLite not executing joins properly?

Tags: sqldelight

I have added SqlDelight to my Multiplatform project and have created a few basic tables and queries.

When I try to use more complex queries though, like `JOINS` the query still executes and the generated interfaces contain all the correct fields, but the actual objects do not contain the generated data.

GithubRepository.sq:

```
CREATE TABLE GithubRepository (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Foobar.sq:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    foobar TEXT NOT NULL,
    repoId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(repoId) REFERENCES GithubRepository(id)
);

findFoobars:
SELECT *
FROM foobar
LEFT JOIN GithubRepository ON GithubRepository.id = foobar.repoId;

insert:
INSERT INTO foobar VALUES ?;
```

Now, I verify that this is working with a couple of tests, like so:

```
    @Test
    fun `Joins working?`() {
        assertEquals(0, queries.findAll().executeAsList().size)

        queries.insert(GithubRepository.Impl(2, "bar"))
        foobarQueries.insert(Foobar.Impl(1, "foo", 2))

        assertEquals("bar", foobarQueries.findFoobars().executeAsList()[0].name)
    }
```

All individual queries succeed and I can write to and read from all the tables as expected.

It just happens that when accessing the query with a `JOIN` the joined property stays empty.

In a more complex setup I have also tested this on an Android emulator, where I can read from all the individual tables, but not from the joined fields.

Can anyone spot where I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experimenting, I realized that I was using an in memory database on Android. After switching that over to a proper file based SQLite database by passing a database name to the `AndroidSqliteDriver` constructor, the `JOINS` are executed correctly and the expected fields are filled correctly.

This seems to be a limitation of the the in memory database driver. I expect that switching the tests over to a file based one will solve the test failures as well.